# Event processing termination in Esper

Tags: esper

Given chain of insert-into statements, for example:

```
on GenericEvent insert into rule_A_stream select *;

on rule_A_stream 
insert into rule_B_stream select * where condition1
insert into rule_C_stream select * where condition2;

on rule_B_stream 
insert into rule_D_stream select * where condition3
insert into rule_E_stream select * where condition4;

on rule_E_stream 
insert into rule_F_stream select * where condition4
insert into rule_G_stream select * where condition5;
```

- How can we terminate Event processing immediately once rule_E_stream is reached and return the results? (termination means stopping event propagation so no following statements should not be invoked)
- Is it possible to stop processing on Subscriber/Listener side?
- Considering using context with “terminated by” Event:

```
create context Ctx initiated by InitEvent terminated by TerminateEvent
```

- I wonder is it applicable in our case?

Answer (score 0):

The @Drop annotation (aka. prioritized execution) terminates. An example would be:

`@Drop @Priority(1) select * from rule_E_stream(drop_conditions_here_if_any)`

`@Priority(0) on rule_E_Stream ....`

Listeners don't stop things in Esper in general. But listeners can reinsert (aka. route) events as a result of their own filter or transformation they may do.